# what do these kernel panic errors mean?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, arm

I `insmod` a kernel module on ARM platform and I get a kernel panic which causes this three errors to be printed to screen

1. `Unhandled fault: external abort on non-linefetch (0x008)`
2. `Unhandled fault: imprecise external abort (0xc06)`
3. `Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt`

   - What are those values in parenthesis ?
   - What does `3` mean It sounds like scheduling while atomic but there is
     no such thing in a kernel module.?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The values in parenthesis are the `ifsr` ([instruction fault status](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344b/Bgbiaghh.html)) register.  There are many causes for aborts and these give a specific cause.  There are some tables in the kernel that handle particular fault causes and other have a handler which does a `printk` and aborts a task or can `panic()` the kernel.  See: [arm/mm/fault.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/fault.c).  The value is probably not valuable unless you are developing a fault handler.  Although it can give an idea of what the fault is about, it is better just to get the `PC` and look at the code at that address (which I think was already printed?).

These faults can occur anywhere; in a user task, a kernel task or an `interrupt` handler, etc.  Since your `interrupt` handler has crashed, Linux decides to stop everything and not bother proceeding.  Otherwise, you could corrupts disks (even more), etc.

Note: Each [*fault status register*](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0198e/I1039321.html) has an *abort.S* file which is different for the particular ARM CPU.  For example see [abort-ev7.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/abort-ev7.S) `v7_early_abort`.  This is put in a [processor table](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/proc-v7.S) which is matched at boot time.

1. *Unhandled fault* - trying to read memory that is not mapped (via MMU).
2. *Kernel panic* - an *unhandled fault* occurred in code deemed un-recoverable.

Comment: Sorry, the tables were recently moved to separate `C` files.  See: [fsr-2level.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/fsr-2level.c) and [fsr-3level.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/fsr-3level.c) for the tables that map `ifsr` to function types.  At least in 2.6.36, these tables were in `fault.c`.  I suppose that some FSR codes may indicate a `hardware` error versus an *un-mapped* page; this is CPU (ie ARMV5, ARMV8, etc) dependent.

Comment: You may have device mapping setup properly. A common case is where the clocks for a peripheral are not enabled and the device does not respond to a bus request; especially *external abort* type messages maybe due to a missing `clk_prepare_enable()`.