# ARM DFSR\ISFR register

Tags: exception, arm, abort

I'm writing an exception handler and I'd like to make use of the FSR ( fault status registers)
I'm using Cortex-A9 , L1\L2 and MMU on , OS is nucleus.

I'm generating different exceptions but it seems that DFSR\ISFR do not change their value after the exception occurred. is there a need to enable this functionality or FSR should be captured by default ?

Ran

Comment: Take a look at [ARM Linux kernel panic errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889483/what-do-these-kernel-panic-errors-mean).  The fault will depend on a what issues the fault.  An *unmapped* page will always return the same value.  Turning a clock off on a peripheral and trying to access a register will issue a different kind of **FSR**.  It has to do with the type of program/data fault.  How is it that you *generate different exceptions*?

Comment: 1. Trying to read from unmapped memory ( 0xFFFF_FFFF ) branches to my
data abort handler. DSFR = 1 and  ISFR =10 before and after the exception.
2. set pc to bad instruction branches to my undefined vector, FSR values are the same.
3. Unaligned access ( SCTRL 'A' bit on ) branches to data abort vector , FSR same values ( 1, 10 ).
4. I'm using same routines for other CP15 regs so I know I read them  the right way

Comment: It is possible that something else is altering them.  `DFSR&0xf` should be **1** for un-aligned.  `DFSR&0xf` should be **5** or **7** for the un-mapped page.  Is your L1 page table fully populated? `mrc p15, 0, rX, c5, c0, 0` is the instruction.  You can see all the [abort-*.S files](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/mm/) in Linux for reference.  Some CPUs seem to have erratas.