# Debugging processor registers when running an MMU

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

I am currently trying to access the registers of the ARM9 core on the Zynq Z702 SoC using the XIlinx's XMD tool provided as part of the SDK. When I try to read a part of memory, I am getting an MMU related error. Do i need some specialized hardware to read and write to these registers when running an OS on the processor.  Please help.

P.S. : I am running Linux 3.x.x kernel on the processor and the memory region I am trying to access are memory mapped regions and are not occupied by any kernel or user-space code.

Comment: Google `ioremap` and get references like [Linux device drivers chapter 9, section 4](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4).  If you have that, then [what do these panic errors mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889483/what-do-these-kernel-panic-errors-mean) maybe helpful.  Often you must clock the peripheral before it will respond to BUS requests.  Giving a specific error from the console (google *early console*, etc and look/`grep` in the *Documentation* directory) will give more information on the type of error.

Comment: Please try to narrow your question by getting specifics on **MMU related error**.  The *what do these panic errors* question gives an easy way to get this.

Comment: *"the memory region I am trying to access are memory mapped regions"* -- Once the kernel enables the MMU for virtual memory operation, all instructions use *virtual* addresses.  Your SoC documentation will list *physical* addresses for those memory-mapped registers.  You have to map those *physical* addresses to *virtual* addresses in order to access those registers.  The MMU error is probably because you are trying to use a physical address, which is being treated as if it was a virtual address.

Comment: Thank you all for providing information. @sawdust: You are correct regarding virtual and physical address translation. But I would like to access the physical addresses corresponding to the virtual addresses I have mapped in user-space. I hope you are getting what I am trying to convey here.

Comment: You cannot use a physical address when the CPU is setup with a MMU for virtual memory.  (Only a DMA controller would need to be programmed with the physical address of a memory buffer.)  If you have a virtual mapping for a physical location, then simply read or write to that virtual address to access that physical location.  The MMU will automatically translate every virtual address to its mapped physical location.

Comment: @sawdust Right and the function to map a physical to virtual is `ioremap()` (and others).  The OP should start looking there.

Comment: @Sawdust: I am particularly interested to know about accessing the physical addresses using a JTAG debugger. Are there any third party debuggers available to access the physical address space while an MMU is running?

Comment: I've never tried using a JTAG probe with Linux.