# ARM7 physical memory damaged. Test from code?

Tags: exception, memory, arm, keil

I have an LPC2220 ARMv7 device. From time to time, when executing my code, it appears Data Abort Exceptions, each time returning a different memory address, and I want to make sure there's nothing related to the physical memory or a chip failure, as my program is using most of the memory space. Is there any way to test the memory? from code?

N.B. I'm using keil uVision for debugging the code

Comment: [Google 'ARM FAR FSR'](https://www.google.ca/search?q=arm+fsr+far), which give descriptions of 'Data aborts'.  What address caused the fault and the exact type of fault.  If the 'Data abort' PC/LR gives a location that is not an `str/ldr`, then your DDR (or SRAM) might be damage.  Otherwise, it is probably a coding error and maybe you use something uninitialized. Maybe [what do these kernel panics mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889483/what-do-these-kernel-panic-errors-mean) can help?

Comment: yes, absoluely, write and run a test.  you are not overclocking your ram are you? note that is an ARM7 not an ARMv7...

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers! I can't tell the address causing it because every time it happens a different return address is set in LR (but the ones I've seen are ldr/str, so it's frustrating). That's why I'm thinking i have a HW problem... but I'd like to be completely sure. I'm currently running a read/write test, but... what would be the key to know if it's a hw or sw problem? I've googled the  FAR/FSR thing, but I still don't know how to be sure of my problem.

Comment: FAR/FSR give further information on what caused the address fault.  The fact the `LR` is always ldr/str indicates that you may have a code problem.  If you have a generic memory issue, then instructions that are normally not ldr/str may change to these.  Ie, memory itself does not distinguish between code/data.  In fact, this concept makes most people think a 'real memory' issue is a code issue (the code does not execute as compiled and printf debug doesn't work).

Comment: Thanks again... I'm trying to discard a hw problem by refreshing values in every memory position, but i don't know if it'll be a good solution... Will check the FAR/FSR when it finishes. Thank you for your advices!