# Page fault handling in Kernel for ARM

Tags: arm, kernel

I am writing a interrupt handlers for a basic kernel running on the ARM processor of a Raspberry Pi. I have the handlers for system call and irq handlers which are handled respectively. The code is taken from https://github.com/pykello/arunos. And I want to add some exokernel features one of which requires a user level page fault handler.

I have experience in x86 kernel development, but being an ARM rookie, I'm stumped on how to implement a page fault handler, that is getting the trapframe, faulting address and then allocating the pages for that address.
Any steps, sites or instructions would be useful.

```
interrupt_table_start:
    nop
    subs pc, lr, #4
    ldr pc, syscall_entry_address
    subs pc, lr, #4
    subs pc, lr, #4
    subs pc, lr, #4
    ldr pc, irq_entry_address
    syscall_entry_address: .word syscall_entry
    irq_entry_address: .word irq_entry
interrupt_table_end:

syscall_entry:
    ldr sp, =kernel_stack_start
    SAVE_CONTEXT

    stmfd r13!, {r1-r12, r14}

    bl handle_syscall

    ldmfd r13!, {r1-r12, pc}^

irq_entry:
    sub r14, r14, #4
    ldr sp, =irq_stack_start
    SAVE_CONTEXT

    stmfd r13!, {r0-r12, r14}

    bl dispatch_interrupts

    ldmfd r13!, {r0-r12, pc}^
```

Comment: No C here. I only see arm and kernel. (But will _[this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/231188/163326)_ help?)

Comment: Realistically, if you don't even know which one the Data Abort vector is, it's time to sit down and study the relevant [architecture reference manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference/index.html#reference) (sign-up required) - v6, v7 or v8 for Pi 1, 2 or 3 respectively. As to how to deal with allocating and mapping pages; it's your OS, you can implement that however you like...

Comment: @Notlikethat I figured out the data abort vector and where to load it in the interrupt vector. I'm only, stumped on what registers to push on to the stack and basically some steps in the right direction.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889483/what-do-these-kernel-panic-errors-mean) might have some interesting information for you.  Basically, you need to know **FSR** and **FAR**; these are CP15 registers which give some of the information you expect.  There are two faults (data/code) and the banking is similar.  Otherwise, your question is very broad as it stands now.  Note:  The **FAR** is only for data faults; it is that data access that caused the fault.  If you want the instruction that faulted, that is banked LR of fault (+8)... and banked *spsr* is the faulted mode.