# What does code 0x017 signifies in unhandled page fault

Tags: c, linux, arm

When verbose user fault messages are enabled in linux kernel and segmentation fault occurs because of any illegal memory access, program crashes with message like

```
unhandled page fault (11) at 0x0839800, code 0x017
```

code which has value 0x017, printed with this message might have different value with other crashes. But what does the code 0x017 signifies here. Can anyone please explain or provide link for resources explaining about it?

Comment: What CPU architecture ? ARM ?

Comment: @ Paul R, Yes the crash is happening on ARM processor.

Comment: OK - I have added the `arm` tag to help avoid any further confusion.

Comment: https://rgeissert.blogspot.se/p/segmentation-fault-error.html

Comment: It seems you don't have root permission

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what do these kernel panic errors mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889483/what-do-these-kernel-panic-errors-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the `si_code`, but the value of ARM's FSR (Fault Status Register) ([source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/fault.c#L169)):

```
 0x17 = 0b1 0111
```

According to [ARM manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0198e/I1039321.html):

> **[Bits 7:4]** Specifies which of the 16 domains (D15-D0) was being accessed
>   when a data fault occurred.
>
> **[Bits 3:0]** Type of fault generated

So domain is 1, which is [`DOMAIN_USER` in the kernel](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/domain.h#L22) (all user memory only). Type of fault is page [`translation fault, page`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344b/Bgbiaghh.html).